# When I apply a median filter in a gray image it gets converted back to a RGB image. Why?

Tags: python, rgb

When I apply a median filter in a gray image it gets converted back to a RGB image. Why?

See code below:

```
path = '/content/img_gray' # Source Folder
dstpath = '/content/img_filtered_gray' # Destination Folder
try:
    makedirs(dstpath)
except:
    print ("Directory already exist, images will be written in same folder")
# Folder won't used
files = list(filter(lambda f: isfile(join(path,f)), listdir(path)))
for image in files:
    try:
        img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,image))
        median = cv2.medianBlur(img,5)
        dstPath = join(dstpath,image)
        cv2.imwrite(dstPath,median)
    except:
        print ("{} is not converted".format(image))
```

Comment: How did you determine that the input image was grayscale and the output image is RGB?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In OpenCV (Python), why am I getting 3 channel images from a grayscale image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18870603/in-opencv-python-why-am-i-getting-3-channel-images-from-a-grayscale-image)

Comment: can you add the input image and output image or shape of the input image and output image

Answer (score 0):

Convert to Gray from BGR before you apply `medianBlur`:

```
img = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
median = cv2.medianBlur(img,5)
```

Note that the default color format in OpenCV is often referred to as RGB but it is actually BGR (the bytes are reversed).